# Incompatible types error in HtmlElementDecorator(driver)

Tags: java, htmlelements

I've started study Yandex Html Elements framework. I do according to start guide https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements-examples/blob/master/htmlelements-junit-example/src/site/junit-example.md

And stop in the beginning

```
public class MainPage {

private WebDriver driver;

@FindBy(className = "b-morda-search-form")
private SearchArrow searchArrow;

public MainPage(final WebDriver driver) {
    PageFactory.initElements(new HtmlElementDecorator(driver), this);
    this.driver = driver;
}

public SearchPage searchFor(String request) {
    this.searchArrow.searchFor(request);
    return new SearchPage(driver);
}
}
```

line

```
 PageFactory.initElements(new HtmlElementDecorator(driver), this);
```

create error

> Error:(26, 59) java: incompatible types: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
>   cannot be converted to
>   ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements.pagefactory.CustomElementLocatorFactory

It's only works like that:

```
PageFactory.initElements(new HtmlElementDecorator(new HtmlElementLocatorFactory(driver)), this);
```

Why?

I'm using IDEA 15 Ultimate, Java 8

pom-file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>vasidizus</groupId>
<artifactId>Autotest</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Autotest</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements</groupId>
  <artifactId>htmlelements-java</artifactId>
  <version>1.15</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements</groupId>
  <artifactId>htmlelements-matchers</artifactId>
  <version>1.15</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.matchers</groupId>
  <artifactId>webdriver-matchers</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.matchers</groupId>
  <artifactId>common-matchers</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>2.48.2</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

```
public HtmlElementDecorator(CustomElementLocatorFactory factory) {
       this.factory = factory;
}
```

So basically the constructor of HtmlElementDecorator only takes CustomElementLocatorFactory, hence the "incompatible types" error.

Just FYI, instead of

```
PageFactory.initElements(new HtmlElementDecorator(new HtmlElementLocatorFactory(driver)), this);
```

you can also use

```
HtmlElementLoader.populatePageObject(this, driver);
```